# AWS CDK Bucket deployment error : No such Bucket exist

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cdk

I am trying to create S3 bucket with some resources using aws cdk. The simple code to create the S3 bucket works perfectly fine but with bucket deployment, it keeps failing with the below error :

```
The specified bucket does not exist (Service: 
 ›   Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code: NoSuchBucket
```

Below is my code :

```
const bucket = new Bucket(this, 'MyBucket', {
      encryption: BucketEncryption.S3_MANAGED,
      bucketName,
      removalPolicy: RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
      blockPublicAccess: {
        blockPublicAcls: true,
        blockPublicPolicy: true,
        restrictPublicBuckets: true,
        ignorePublicAcls: true
      }
    });
  

    new BucketDeployment(this, id, {
      sources: [Source.asset('./resources/')],
      destinationBucket: bucket,
      prune: false
    });
```

Is there anything that I am missing here ?

Thanks

Comment: Do I understand correctly:  First, you deploy a stack with a `Bucket` construct.  "Works perfectly fine".  Next, you modify the stack by adding the `BucketDeployment` construct.  Deploy fails.  Is that what's happening?

Comment: Does it work if you don't do the blockPublic stuff?

Comment: There might be one exception prior to that. I had this issue when the lambda ran out of local disk space but this error was thrown upfront. Can you check your whole stacktrace and if your deployment does not exceed 512mb?

Comment: @fedonev yes. They both dont work together - bucket creation and deployment within same stack.